# Drop all rows of multiple pandas dataframes where date index not included in all others

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes with different starting dates, and want to drop the rows which have dates not included in all other dataframes.

Example:

```
df1=
0 X Y   
2020-03-16  0.0 0.0
2020-03-17  0.0 0.0
...

df2=
0 X Y   
2020-03-01  0.0 0.0
2020-03-02  0.0 0.0
...

df3=
0 X Y   
2020-03-02  0.0 0.0
2020-03-03  0.0 0.0
...
```

--> All three dataframes should start with 2020-03-16

I tried:

```
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3]
new = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on="0",how='inner'), data_frames)
```

But I get errors - do you know how this could be solved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `concat` with `drop_duplicates`

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0).drop_duplicates(keep=False, subset=["0"])

print(df)

            0    X    Y
0  2020-03-16  0.0  0.0
1  2020-03-17  0.0  0.0
0  2020-03-01  0.0  0.0
1  2020-03-03  0.0  0.0
```